# CompareTo method - how do I use it with does not equal?

Tags: java

I've been working on this problem for hours and can't figure it out. I'm taking a string variable through user input and comparing that to values in an array. The first if statement executes fine when the value is present in the array. However, whether the value is present or not, the second if statement is executing when it should only be executing when the value is not present in the array.

```
// begin the calculate() function on the condition that XXX is not typed
  while (addIn.compareTo("XXX") != 0) {

      for (x = 0; x < NUM_ITEMS; x++) {

          if (addIn.compareTo(addIns[x]) == 0) {
             System.out.println("The price of " + addIn + " is $" + addInPrices[x]);
             orderTotal += addInPrices[x];
          }

          if (addIn.compareTo(addIns[x]) != 0) {
              System.out.println("Sorry, we don't carry that.");
              addIn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter coffee add-in or " + END + " to quit: ");
          }

     }

     addIn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your next add-in, or XXX to complete your order!");
 }

 System.out.println("Your total is $" + orderTotal + ". Your order will be out shortly!");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've tried that, it still executes both statements for some reason.

Comment: You should probably use the else statement. And no, both if and else will never be executed

Comment: @Oshan_Mendis Not in the same test, but across multiple iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You're executing the second statement for *every* non-matching item in the array. What you need to do instead is set a flag and check it at the end of the loop:

```
// begin the calculate() function on the condition that XXX is not typed
while (addIn.compareTo("XXX") != 0) {

    boolean found = false;
    for (x = 0; x < NUM_ITEMS; x++) {
        if (addIn.compareTo(addIns[x]) == 0) {
            found = true;
            System.out.println("The price of " + addIn + " is $" + addInPrices[x]);
            orderTotal += addInPrices[x];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, we don't carry that.");
        addIn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter coffee add-in or " + END + " to quit: ");
    } else {
        addIn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your next add-in, or XXX to complete your order!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This one did it! I think I understand why I was so off the first time. It also makes way more sense to use that else statement over what I had before. Thank you so much for your help.